Interface id of ERC4337 smart contract acccount
Has the community already agreed on a way to identify an ERC4337-compliant smart contract wallet? For example, using ERC165? What would be the interface Id for it since only one of the 2 function signatures is clearly defined in the EIP? And if not, is there any way to programmatically know if a contract is an ERC4337-compliant SCA?
